# Auto generate testcases for codeigniter

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, phpunit

How to generate testcases for codeigniter or any other MVC based project using the command **phpunit-skelgen** and I have to create testcases with assertions automatically.

Comment: I would also like to know how to generate the project automatically as well: so you just pass the job description to the special program, and when you come back from the shop with beer - it's already done.

Comment: @zerkms: Refer first http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/skeleton-generator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now I got solution for this problem,

We can use bootstrap file in **netbeans**, then enable create unit test cases check box,
then right click corresponding file and we can create unit test cases.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html